# Javascript Functioncall Socket.io and Phaser

Tags: javascript, function, socket.io, phaser-framework

I have a problem with a function call with Phaser. I am a Javascript Noob and don´t know what I do wrong.

Here is the critical Part of my Code, all the code is in the same file.

```
BasicGame.Multiplayer = function (game) {
};

  BasicGame.Multiplayer.prototype = {

        create: function(){
            this.socket = io.connect('localhost:3010');
            this.socket.on('startGame', function () {
                console.log('ShouldStartGame');
                this.createActualGame();
            });
},

createActualGame: function(){
        // Define constants
       }
}
```

My problem is that the function this.createActualGame is not called with the error: "TypeError: this.createActualGame is not a function".
But the console log works fine.

Without the socket.on(...) the code works fine and the function is called with the statement "this.createActualGame()", but wihtin the socket.on(...) it doesn´t work and i have no clue why and no idea how this could be solved. Thank you very much for your help.

With kind regards,
SirSandmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either:

```
    create: function(){
        this.socket = io.connect('localhost:3010');
        this.socket.on('startGame', function () {
            console.log('ShouldStartGame');
            this.createActualGame();
        }.bind(this));
    },
```

Or just:

`BasicGame.Multiplayer.createActualGame();`

Comment: Hey, thanks for you fast reply, but neither of the options work.
For the .bind option I get the errors "TypeError: socket.on(...).bind is not a function Multiplayer.js:18:0
TypeError: this.createActualGame is not a function" and for the BasicGame.Multiplayer.createActualGame() i get the same "TypeError: this.createActualGame is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

```
socket = io.connect('localhost:3010');
        socket.on('startGame', function () {
            console.log('ShouldStartGame');
            this.createActualGame();
        }.bind(this));
```

Is the solution for the problem. (you set the brackets wrong way)